# Extract Components From a 3-in-1 Printer

Tags: arduino, components

I have a fairly recent 3-in-1 Cannon ink jet printer, which works fine accept creating a small skew on the printing page. I wanted to just throw it away, but was wondering if I can pull out components from it and use it with an Arduino?

It has a color LCD, Sensor in the scanner and it probably has a few servo motors. Are my assumptions correct? Would they be in a form where I can remove them and use them?

**Update**

Printer Model: [PIXMA MP 470](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/printers_multifunction/pixma_mp_series/pixma_mp470#ServiceAndSupport)

Comment: This question is a bit too broad, in that it does not provide the printer model number or any inside photos, which would have enabled a considered response in terms of which parts could be liberated in a usable state. However, if you are throwing it away anyway, just go ahead and open it up: From personal experience, at least the motors (servos, steppers), the LCD panel (if it uses a commonly known protocol e.g. SPI or I2C) and the mechanical assembly come in handy for experimentation. The power supply might also come in handy, it usually sits on a separate board and can be extracted easily.

Comment: More likely stepper motors than servos; easy to drive. Plus some nice precision steel bar guides, belts and gears. The LCD will be undocumented and therefore difficult to use; good luck with that!

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I've added the model number for the printer with the link to its support site.

Comment: @BrianDrummond - many inkjet printers retain a stepper for paper feed, but use a servo motor for cross feed, often closing the loop with a linear optical encoder strip, or a rotary one on very early models.

Comment: The tinkerers who do this kind of stuff do not have to ask! It is futile and they know it. If you want to know if you can use parts from a printer, the only way is to try it. No support site will guide you in this sort of information.

Comment: @Chris Stratton : not seen one with a servo motor yet; perhaps all my Epsons were too old. Which makes/models give you a linear opto encoder strip? My lathes want to know!

Comment: Don't throw away the power supply!

Comment: @jippie the power supply to most printers I've seen are either multi-voltage with odd voltage selections (I haven't seen a 12v yet), AC, or negative voltages even. They ain't really useful expect for other similar printers.

Comment: @Passerby One inkjet printer I "liberated" had a nice power board with a +12V, +5V and +3.3V, plus one other output I cannot recall, some negative voltage.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh internal power supply? What kind of power cable? All the ones I've seen have external regulators.

Comment: @Passerby 220 Volt regular power supply, no external power brick. Come to think of it, the two working printers I have here are both with regular 220 Volt power cords, therefore internal power boards.

Comment: @Passerby - if the external power brick puts out a weird voltage like 18v then it's a good bet it's being interally regulated down to 12v/5v/3v3/1v8 for the electronics - very few people use 18v microcontrollers!

Comment: And to answer the OP - any electronic component/device can be re-used, it's just a question of what's worth using vs the time & effort required. I made the paper feed mechanics of one into a barrel polisher. Using the head/feed mechanism(s) from printers/scanners as the axes for 3D printers or CNC mills/cutters is popular (see Hackaday.com).

Comment: @JohnU Thank you for answering the question! If you would like put your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made this an answer by request...

Any electronic component/device can be re-used, it's just a question of what's worth using vs the time & effort required. I made the paper feed mechanics of one into a barrel polisher. Using the head/feed mechanism(s) from printers/scanners as the axes for 3D printers or CNC mills/cutters is popular (see Hackaday.com).

Also see Tim Hunkin's website for various genius ideas.